# Why is the Taproot Merkle path length limited to 128?

Tags: taproot, mast

From [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki#cite_note-6):

> **Why is the Merkle path length limited to 128?** The optimally
> space-efficient Merkle tree can be constructed based on the
> probabilities of the scripts in the leaves, using the Huffman
> algorithm. This algorithm will construct branches with lengths
> approximately equal to *log<sub>2</sub>(1/probability)*, but to have branches
> longer than 128 you would need to have scripts with an execution
> chance below 1 in *2<sup>128</sup>*. As that is our security bound, scripts that
> truly have such a low chance can probably be removed entirely.

This is an excellent explanation why one really doesn't need a Merkle tree deeper than 128, but it doesn't explain why it's not allowed. Would this open the protocol to some sort of attack? I don't see how a script path spend with a few thousand branch steps would be worse than multiple individual transactions with shorter branches. Or it is just a standard to set a limit like this in a protocol when confident enough that nobody could ever need to go over it?

Comment: Heh, don't you think that being able to have up 3.402823669×10³⁸ leafscripts is enough?— I think you mistook the limit to be 128 instead of 2^128.  ;)

Comment: @Murch I believe that OP by "a few thousand branches" means "a single control block with a few thousand Merkle branch steps". The actual number of possible branches isn't relevant here, as only one gets revealed.

Comment: Ah, right. That makes actually a lot more sense.

Comment: Observation by Pieter is correct. I'm definitely not suggesting the limit isn't generous enough, as no one will be going around constructing Merkle trees with 2^128 different valid conditions anytime soon. But constructing an output with a spendable Merkle path 128 branches long is very much possible.